# GT-I9000G - updated to ICS, charging using USB - error sim card not detected and unable to detect USB drive

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

I just updated my phone to ICS, using samsung galaxy GT-I900G, now whenever I charge my phone using USB, there is a circle icon and the network connection is lost. My machine does not recognize my phone as well. USB error.

Comment: For the second part: have you installed the USB drivers?

Comment: yea. installed usb drivers. tested my phone on another computer. it detected samsung galaxy s3, plugged in this s2, device not recognised.